# Python dynamic web table update

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've an script that goes to a web site and put a value into a search box. After this, it clicks on the search button and a dynamic web table start loading the results availables (I think the table is is Ajax).

I want to copy the results but when they're ready. Until now what I did it was just to wait a certain amount of time hoping that the results were ready after this time but It has not always been the case. There is no web site address change or refresh of the site itself.

I've found that a parameter 'aria-busy="true"' indicates when the table object is searching for the results. It only appears when the table is updating and then it dissapears. Just after the click on the search button I've used this code in order to see this parameter become 'True':

```
self.Chromium.find_element(By.ID, 'button-1511').click()
    
for i in range(0,10):
    print(self.Chromium.find_element(By.ID, "gridpoOverview").get_attribute("aria-busy"))
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

The output for a given search :

> None true true None None None None None None

So I can detect when this parameter appears and becomes true. How can I set an explcit condition which waits the condition to appear, to become true, then false (this is the sequence that allows me to verify that the table has been updated)  and do whatever I want to do next ?

Comment: When you press search button, do you expect specific row? do you already knows the content of that row? if yes then you can wait until that expected contents.

Comment: Another idea is you can take a count of total rows each time in a loop and compare with previous count and current count always. when you will find equal, it means the dynamic table are loaded.

Comment: I don’t know the number of rows. The reference can also be not found and no results will be shown or even two consecutive references can have the same number of rows. I want to use an explicit wait condition in order to see this attribute appears, then disappear and that way I’ll know the table has been updated